# Compiler and linker flags for Intel Advisor

Tags: compilation, linker, intel, icc, intel-parallel-studio

I'm using an Intel C++ v16 compiler on a Xeon Phi Knights Landing (KNL) on an application using OpenMP. I'm reading about what compiler and linker options to use for the [Vectorization Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-advisor-vectorization-linux), the [Thread Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-advisor-threading-linux) and finally [VTune](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/605665).

Combining the tables in the 3 linked documents, I came up with this list (considering that Xeon Phi KNL supports AVX512):

```
-g -O3 -parallel -Bdynamic -ldl -simd -qopenmp -parallel-source-info=2 -qopenmp-link dynamic -debug inline-debug-info -shared-intel -xCORE-AVX512
```

However, I don't know which of these flags has to be used during compiling and/or linking. In second place, am I missing any useful flag (or some of them are redundant)?

Btw, this happens compiling opencv.

Comment: I use `icc -O3 -xMIC-AVX512 -fopenmp` on KNL. I think you can also use `icc -O3 -xHost -fopenmp`.

Comment: -fopenmp is deprecated. And why do you use MIC instead of CORE?

Comment: `-fopenmp` still works. I use `-xMIC-AVX512` because it's made for KNL which has AVX512ER and other features (and some missing ones) which you don't get with `-xCORE-AVX512`.